# Parse facebook login issue?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am trying to implement facebook login using Psrse.
The following code works if the user has facebook login in their iOS settings, but if they don't it doesn't work.

As soon as I call `logInWithPermissions` safari opens facebook, and my delegate gets called with nil user, and nil error. When user logins on safari, it takes the user back to the app, `application:openURL:sourceApplication` gets called, but the completion of `logInWithPermissions` never gets triggered

Been spending 3 days trying to resolve this. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I already added all keys to info.plist as well

there is a duplicate here that doesn't solve the issue: [iOS/Swift: PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions returns nil user and error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387877/ios-swift-pffacebookutils-loginwithpersmissions-returns-nil-user-and-error)

```
let permissionArray = ["public_profile", "email"]

PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissionArray) { user, error in

     println(user)
     println(error)

}
```

Appdelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBAppCall.handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession(PFFacebookUtils.session())
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, withSession: PFFacebookUtils.session())
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added this to   application:openUrl:sourceApplication and all values are there and valid after login.

```
println(url)
println(sourceApplication)
println(PFFacebookUtils.session())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code causing the issue was this.
Session doesn't exist already so calling close was causing a crash when opening safari with no exception logs. Then coming back to the app it would start the app from scratch, but since it would go back to the login page it was hard to tell.

Need to check to see if session exists or not before calling clode.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    PFFacebookUtils.session().close()
}
```