# Parse: User and error both nil with logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions()

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am using Xcode 7.1, Swift 2, Parse 1.9.1, and Facebook SDK 4.7.1. I've been using `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions` on iOS 8 perfectly fine, but as soon as I updated to iOS 9 I've been unable to use it. Every time I log in using this:

```
        let permissions = ["email"]
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            print(user)
            print(error)

            if let user = user {
                if user.isNew {
                    print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                } else {
                    print("User logged in through Facebook!")
                }
            } else {
                print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

I get `Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.` and with `nil` user and error. I've seemingly tried everything; making a blank Xcode project from scratch, adding `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and `App Transport Security Settings` to my .plist, double checking bundle ID. Pretty positive I've added all required Parse and Facebook methods to my App Delegate.

Is this a Parse bug? All of a sudden it doesn't work and I can't log in to my app. Am I missing something?

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Initialize Parse.
        Parse.setApplicationId("XXXX",
            clientKey: "XXXX")

        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
return (FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)) || (true)

    }
func application(application: UIApplication,
        openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication: String?,
        annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
            return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                openURL: url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation)

    }
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Comment: Have you updated to the most recent Facebook and Parse SDKs?

Comment: Yes, both are the most recent.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387877/ios-swift-pffacebookutils-loginwithpersmissions-returns-nil-user-and-error  Also make sure that on the iPhone in the Settings ->Facebook the app is not disabled

Comment: The thing is, my app never shows up under Settings -> Facebook, so it's neither on nor off

Comment: @dperk Found any solution to this issue?

Comment: @dperk also interested!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you configure Parse (probably in the appDel), call `PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()` after, this should solve that problem.